# Which OSS can extract a synopsis from a text?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, nlp, text-processing

Is there an OSS which can compress a text to a synopsis?

My goal is to build an editor for SciFi novels which can either automatically create a synopsizes for chapters or at least make a suggestion for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the comprehensive list [here](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/web/competition.html), and the [Dragon Toolkit](http://dragon.ischool.drexel.edu/default.asp) looked like one of the few to offer [this feature](http://dragon.ischool.drexel.edu/textsum.asp). My experience is mainly with the commercial tools in this area.

Comment: How well does automatic summarization work? Is it practical yet or more an area of research?

Comment: It's more of an area of research and tends to be limited to specific document types. I find it unlikely that it would work on novels.

Answer (score 0):

Try bringing the books, a couple typewriters, a case of Red Bull, and some bananas to the monkeys at your local zoo. They do a good job but you'll have to clean the poo off the machines :-)